# How to get most up-to-date redux value while in loop?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I just went thru scenario below and feeling weird about it.

Basically in my component, I will use an `inputList` from redux store, loop it thru, update some field of it. Pseudocode as below

```js
//Before onClick, this.props.inputList as below:
[
  { id: 1, active: 1, name: 'john' },
  { id: 2, active: 1, name: 'cena' },
  { id: 3, active: 2, name: 'oldValue' },
]

onClick = () => {
  this.props.inputList
    .filter(x => x.active === 2)
    .forEach(x => {
      //Update name to 'newValue' and submit to backend

      this.props.reduxAction_updateField({ fieldName: 'name', value: 'newValue'});

      //********
      console.log(x) //x.name remained 'oldValue' which make sense.
      //Try to use Store.getState().myReducer.inputList
      const expectUpdatedElement = Store.getState().myReducer.inputList
                                   .find(y => y.id === 3);

      //expectUpdatedElement.name === 'oldValue'?????
      //********

      //Make API Request with updated info
      ...
    })
}
```

As shown above, I've used `forEach` loop and update the field `name` to `newValue`, using redux action.

While in the loop, I use `Store.getState().myReducer.inputList`, instead of `this.props.inputList`, thinking will get the updated list but it doesnt seems like the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this](https://redux.js.org/faq/design-decisions):

> Subscribers are intended to respond to the state value itself, not the
>   action. Updates to the state are processed synchronously, but
>   notifications to subscribers can be batched or debounced, meaning that
>   subscribers are not always notified with every action. This is a
>   common performance optimization to avoid repeated re-rendering.

The thing is, your component is a subscriber and as soon as you try to update the state, it cannot guarantee you that you'll get most updated state as soon as you've dispatched the action.

What you should do is, make a variable what you'd want to store in the state, make your API call with that variable and then update the store simultaneously.

```
const values = [
  { id: 1, active: 1, name: 'john' },
  { id: 2, active: 1, name: 'cena' },
  { id: 3, active: 2, name: 'oldValue' },
]

onClick = () => {
  this.props.inputList
    .filter(x => x.active === 2)
    .forEach(x => {
      //Update name to 'newValue' and submit to backend

      //get updatedInfo in a variable
      const updatedInfo = values.find(y => y.name === x.name);

      //make redux redux to update the value
      this.props.reduxAction_updateValue({ value: updatedInfo});

      //Make API Request with updatedInfo variable
      ...
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what could be the problem without a proper code sample (and I can't comment cos I'm new). But assuming you have the store set up correctly, it may be because you are expecting to get the reducer from getState but getState just returns the most recent state set by a reducer, or is your data set up so the reducer name is the data object property name?